# How to change the xaxis labels in seaborn lineplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

Below is the image of line plot i have plot. Is there a way to show on x axis year from 2008 to the 2020. currently it is skipping odd ones.

[image: line plot]

Comment: This depends on the type of data you have on the xaxis. Are you plotting `int`, `datetime`...?

Comment: @AndreaBlengino  plotting int.

Comment: @AndreaBlengino i figured in int. However unable to figure in case of timeseries data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution depends on the type of your xaxis array.
If your xaxis is a `datetime`, you can set the xaxis ticks with

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(base = 1))
```

as the code in this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

requestYear = pd.date_range(start = '2008-01-01', end = '2021-01-01', freq = 'Y')
value = np.random.rand(len(requestYear))

plt.plot(requestYear, value)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(base = 1, month = 12, day = 31))
plt.gca().set_xlim(requestYear[0], requestYear[-1])

plt.show()
```

which provides this plot:

[image]

On the contrary, if your xaxis array is a `int` type, you can use

```
plt.gca().set_xticks(np.arange(requestYear[0], requestYear[-1] + 1, 1))
```

as in this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

requestYear = np.arange(2008, 2021)
value = np.random.rand(len(requestYear))

plt.plot(requestYear, value)

plt.gca().set_xticks(np.arange(requestYear[0], requestYear[-1] + 1, 1))
plt.gca().set_xlim(requestYear[0], requestYear[-1])

plt.show()
```

which gives this plot:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. Howvever iam getting black 1999-2007 in front of the 2008. I tried adding plt.xlim('2008-01-01,'2020-03-10') it didn't work. Is there a way to avoid it.